# How do I add an image to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, embedded-resource

I am trying to add an image to a JButton and I'm not sure what I'm missing. When I run the following code the button looks exactly the same as if I had created it without any image attribute. Water.bmp is in the root of my project folder.

```
ImageIcon water = new ImageIcon("water.bmp");
    JButton button = new JButton(water);
    frame.add(button);
```

Comment: That **should** work...can you try using the `URL` form of the `ImageIcon` constructor and see what it does? It might be that it can't find the image file for some reason.

Comment: Yes, it's working now. No changes to the code. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I think that your problem is in the location of the image. You shall place it in your source, and then use it like this:

```
  JButton button = new JButton();
  try {
    Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/water.bmp"));
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
  }
```

In this example, it is assumed that image is in src/resources/ folder.

Comment: I dont know why but this didnt work either for me. I even build a function which searched the wanted files in the directory and found them - still no icons. So, i just use the line:           button1.setIcon("path/pic.png");

- this runs. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 18):

@Rogach

and you may like to add:

```
// to remote the spacing between the image and button's borders
button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
// to add a different background
button.setBackground( ... );
// to remove the border
button.setBorder(null);
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a location problem because that code is perfectly fine for adding the icon.

Since I don't know your folder structure, I suggest adding a simple check:

```
File imageCheck = new File("water.bmp");

if(imageCheck.exists()) 
    System.out.println("Image file found!")
else 
    System.out.println("Image file not found!");
```

This way if you ever get your path name wrong it will tell you instead of displaying nothing. Exception should be thrown if file would not exist, tho.

Answer (score 6):

You put your image in resources folder and use follow code:

```
JButton btn = new JButton("");
btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Class.class.getResource("/resources/img.png")));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ImageButton extends JButton {

    protected ImageButton(){
    }

    @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("water.bmp");

        g2.drawImage(img, 45, 35, this);
        g2.finalize();
    }
}
```

---

**OR use this code**

```
class MyButton extends JButton {

    Image image;
    ImageObserver imageObserver;


    MyButtonl(String filename) {
            super();
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(filename);
            image = icon.getImage();
            imageObserver = icon.getImageObserver();
        }

     public void paint( Graphics g ) {
            super.paint( g );
            g.drawImage(image,  0 , 0 , getWidth() , getHeight() , imageObserver);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too complex. There is a built-in mechanism for adding icons to buttons, why create additional problems?

Comment: @Rogach Not specifically for this question, but in my case it was useful to have further control on where the image was placed in the button.

Answer (score 2):

I did only one thing and it worked for me .. check your code is this method there ..

```
setResizable(false);
```

if it false make it true and it will work just fine ..
I hope it helped ..

Comment: the frame (?) being resizable or not is irrelevant

Comment: Yes you maybe right .. but when you have a Borderlayout and then you make this statement.. you restrict the frame .. thus if you make true it will give your frame the space.

Answer (score 2):

```
buttonB.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("imagename")));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//paste required image on C disk
JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:water.bmp");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me:

```
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        URL file = getClass().getResource("water.bmp");
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        System.err.println("load error: " + ioex.getMessage());
    }
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
    JButton quitButton = new JButton(icon);
```

Answer (score 1):

For example if you have image in folder `res/image.png` you can write:

```
try
{
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("image.png");
    // URL input = classLoader.getResource("image.png"); // <-- You can use URL class too.
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In one line:

```
try
{
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("image.png"))));
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If the image is bigger than button then it will not shown.

Answer (score 0):

**eclipse example:**
After reading the above, it still took me more research to understand, where and how to place image resources, using eclipse.
The outcome: **in eclipse you need to store images underneath any "Source Folder" (such as "src") or below in a "Folder".**
You create both by right-clicking on your project, "New"->"Source Folder" or "New"->"Folder". Any folder name is fine. Examples for "<Source Folder>/<image Folder>" are "src/images" or "resource/img".
Here's some fully functioning sample code, which expects two button images, "Button-Image-Up.png" and "Button-Image-Down.png" in folder "images":

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImageButtonDlg extends JDialog {
    // define button images and fall-back text
    private static gstrTxt="<Button Fall-back Text>"; // in case image does not load
    private static String gstrImgUp="Button-Image-Up.png";   // regular image
    private static String gstrImgDown="Button-Image-Down.png"; // button pressed image
    private static String gstrImgFolder="images";   // image folder, "/images" is also fine
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageButtonDlg dialog = new ImageButtonDlg();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public ImageButtonDlg() {
        initializeDialog();
    }
    /**
     * Create a new ImageIcon from an image resource. 
     * The input can be: 
     * - an image file name, e.g. <image.png> 
     * - a relative path, e.g. <image/image.png>
     * - an absolute path, e.g. </home/user/dev/image.png>
     * In eclipse, images can be stored below any project "Source folder", 
     * such as "src".
     * ├── src
     * │   ├── img1.png
     * │   └── images
     * │       └── img2.png
     * ├── resources
     * │   ├── img3.png
     * │   └── images
     * │       └── img4.png
     * └── img5.png
     *  In above example img1.png to img4.png are found by 
     *  image file name or relative path
     *  However, img5 is stored in the project root folder and 
     *  needs an absolute path.
     *    
     * @param strImagePath - image filename, absolute path or relative path
     * @return new ImageIcon or 'null' if load fails
     */    
    public static ImageIcon getResourceImageIcon(String strFilepath) {
        ClassLoader loader = null;
        URL url = null;
        Image img=null;
        ImageIcon imgIcon=null;
        loader = ImageButtonDlg.class.getClassLoader();
        System.out.println(loader.toString());
        try {  // file location: <a relative path>
            url = loader.getResource("images/"+strFilepath);
            if(url==null) {
                System.out.printf("ImageButtonDlg.class.getResource(%s)=>null\n", "images/"+strFilepath);
            }
        } catch (Exception e0) {
            e0.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(url==null) {
            try {  // file location: <image filename>
                url = loader.getResource(strFilepath);
                if(url==null) { 
                    System.out.printf("Util.class.getResource(%s)=>null\n", strFilepath);
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (img!=null){
            imgIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
        }
        return imgIcon;
    }
    /**
     * Create JButton with Image
     * In case Image load fails, we create a JButton with text
     * @param strImgPath - path to Image
     * @param strAltText - fall-back text
     * @return
     */
    public static JButton getNewJButtonWithImageIcon(String strImgPath, String strAltText) {
        JButton btnReturn = null;
        ImageIcon imgIcon = getResourceImageIcon(strImgPath);
        if (imgIcon!=null){
            btnReturn = new JButton(imgIcon);
        }
        else {
            btnReturn = new JButton(strAltText);
        }
        return btnReturn;
    }
    /**
     * Image button was pressed, display a message box
     */
    private void actionImageButtonPressed() {
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image Button was pressed", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            ; // ignore
        }
    }
    /**
     * Initialize the dialog
     * add a button panel and the image button to the window/content pane
     */
    private void initializeDialog()
    {
        this.setTitle("Image Button Example");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setBounds(200, 200, 699, 601);
        JPanel panelButton = new JPanel();
        panelButton.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT)); // all buttons in a row
        getContentPane().add(panelButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // button pane at the bottom of the window
        // create the Image Button
        JButton btnImageButton = getNewJButtonWithImageIcon(gstrImgUp, gstrTxt);
        btnImageButton.setToolTipText("<Explain what pressing the Button does>");
        btnImageButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                actionImageButtonPressed();// The Action
            }
        });
        // load button image when button clicked/released
        btnImageButton.addMouseListener((MouseListener) new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                btnImageButton.setIcon(getResourceImageIcon(gstrImgDown));              
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                btnImageButton.setIcon(getResourceImageIcon(gstrImgUp));
            }
        });
        btnImageButton.setActionCommand("ImageButtonAction");
        // add button to button panel
        panelButton.add(btnImageButton);
    }
}
```

**Have Fun!**
**Volker Fröhlich**
P.S.:
Perhaps someone can share additional practical experience.

- In eclipse "WindowBuilder Editor" such image buttons are shown, but they cannot be accessed - is there some workaround?
- What is the NetBeans approach, if any different?