# Java - Adding Images to JButtons

Tags: java, image, swing, button, jbutton

I want to add images to JButtons.  Here is the code I am using:

The images are in a folder called "Images", which happens to be in the source package of the application.  The size of the JButtons is adjusted correctly, however no image is displayed in the button.  Can someone help me solve this problem please?  Thanks :)

Comment: You could take a look at [this to compare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691832/how-to-put-an-image-on-a-jbutton)

Comment: Please have a look at how to [add images to your Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230) for more clarification, if you doing it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `create_ImageIcon(Button_NewFile, "src/Images/New File.png");`

When you create an `ImageIcon`, it searches for relative paths where the application is launched. Normally this is in the folder where **src** folder is located. But have in mind that when you run it as an independent application.

Comment: I will once the timer lets me do it :)