# Buttons with Images

Tags: java, image, swing, button

I am trying to make a Java application.  The java application is supposed to have a menu bar with a flow layout.

Now, in this menu bar, I want to introduce three buttons:

1. To start a new project
2. To open a saved project
3. To save a project

I want to make use of images in these buttons.  Much like Word associated an image of a blank sheet of paper to start a new project, a directory to open a saved project, and a diskette to save a project.

How can this be done in Java please?

**Edit**

I tried this code:

```
UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directoryIcon");
UIManager.getIcon("FileView.fileIcon");
UIManager.getIcon("FileView.floppyDriveIcon");
```

Comment: I am new to Java GUI programming.  I tried to assign an image to a JButton, and was successful.  However, I can't seem to find the images I want.

Comment: > However, I can't seem to find the images I want. How does this relate to Java?

Comment: I can't show you an image because I don't have that privilege as yet.  To give you an idea, look at the icons that Microsoft Word 2003 uses in order to let the user start a new document, open a document and save an existing document.  I want to use those precise three icons but don't know if they are available using the method I used.

Comment: Ok, I understand now what you trying do. How about capturing those images into png files and then loading from them?

Comment: Thanks.  Good idea.  I thought that Java would provide them in-built.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there standard images available in Java, I believe there is not.

But you can capture those images or download a pack.

Then you just use the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4801452/1360074)

```
JButton button = new JButton();


  try {
    Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/water.bmp"));
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Path to the image.format");
JButton btnOne = new JButton();
btnOne.setBackground(icon);
```

Where the path is the location of capured images of what you want as background.