# Why my Jar doesn't run unless I extract files?

Tags: java, image, swing, jar, export

Every time I run the exported `.jar` file, that contains a `JFrame` with an image as its icon, the file doesn't run, **unless I extract the file**. In the compiler it is running. I dont want to make a launcher that saves both, the resources package and the jar file, in a directory.

Comment: Does the code load the resources using a `File` or `String`?  When they have become embedded resources they must be accessed by `URL`.

Comment: Examine how to use [resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html), here is a lot of same questions, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801386/how-do-i-add-an-image-to-a-jbutton).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Why my Jar doesn't run unless I extract files?"

This seems to be the behavior of using `File` to your resources. Take for example

```
File file = new File("resources/image.png");
Image image = ImagIO.read(file);
```

And you project structure (Note the `resources` should actually be in the `src`, so that it builds into the jar automatically - unless you configure it differently. But for the sake of this argument, let's say you *do* confgigure it where `resources` is built to the jar)

```
C:\
   Project
        resources\image.png
```

Some examination:

- Run from IDE - WORKS! Why? Using `File` looks for files on the file system. Using a relative path, the search will begin from the "working directory", which in the case of the IDE in generally the project root. So `"resources/image.png"` is a valid path, relative to `ProjectRoot`
- Build jar, say it ends up in a `dist` dir in the project. This is what it looks like

  ```
  ProjectRoot
           dist
              ProjectRoot.jar
  ```

  Now for the sake of this argument (and is actually the correct way), let's try and print the URL of the resource in out program, so that when you run the jar, it prints out the URL of the file

  ```
  URL url = Test.class.getResource("/resources/image.png");
  System.out.println(url.toString());
  ```

  When we run the jar `C:\ProjectRoot\dist> java -jar ProjectRoot.jar` We will see the print out `C:\ProjectRoot\dist\ProjectRoot.jar!\resources\image.png`. You can obviously see even though the current working directory is the location of the jar, the paths no longer match, with the added jar `ProjectRoot.jar!` location.
- So why does it work when we extract it. Well when you extract it, then the path is correct

  ```
  C:\ProjectRoot
             dist
                 resources/image.png // from extracted jar
                 ProjectRoot.jar
  ```

  When you run from the `C:\ProjectRoot\dist >`, the `resource` dir is where is should be.

**Ok enough with the explanation.**

For this reason, when you want to read embedded resources, they should be read from an URL as Andrew Thompson mentioned.  This url should be relative to the class calling it, or the class loader. Here are a couple different ways:

1. As shown already

   ```
   URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/image.png");
   ```

   Notice the `/`. This will bring us to the root of the classpath, where the `resources` dir will be. `URL` can be passed to many constructors, like `ImageIcon(URL)` or `ImageI.read(URL)
2. You can use:

   ```
   InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/image.png");
   ```

   Which will use an URL under the hood. You can use `InputStream` with many constructors also.
3. There's also ways to use the class loader, which will start at the root, so you don't need the `/`

   ```
   URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/image.png");
   ```

So there are a few ways you can go about it. But in general, reading `File` with hard coded string paths is never a good idea, when using embedded resources. It's possible to obtain the path dynamically so you can use `File`, but you will still need to use one of the aforementioned techniques, which unless you really need a `File` would be pointless, as you can do what you need with the `InputStream` or `URL`

---

### To make a long story short

This would work

```
ProjectRoot
       src\resources\image.png

URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/image.png");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Comment: Thank you for your proper and clear explanation I already did use the URL and `getClass().getResource(PATH)` it appears that I wrote .PNG instead of .png but java case-sensitivity didn't noticed it maybe because it understood the ending in the compiler (Just a guess but maybe because in the compiler it also created instance .PNG of the image) and I verified it by trying to add another images. so for short, thank you very much and cheers.