# Change maven's export resource directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using Maven. When I launch my project from Eclipse, resources are exported at the root directory. But when I export it to an executable jar-file resources are located in `/resources/`

How can I change the path where resources are exported when i launch the project from Eclipse to match the path in executable jar-file ?

Comment: Show your pom.xml

Comment: Nothing special : https://pastebin.com/PCpsSssp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this within `<build></build>` tag :

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>/resources</targetPath>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

You should keep under src/main/resources. Thats the standard.

Comment: This is a workaround. This will tells Eclipse to copy your resources in project/target/resources. You will then need to adjust your code to prefix your resource names with "/resources". This, just to be able to use the export as runnable jar menu option instead of using maven to build the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a working maven POM, (you haven't posted the `<build>` section), the error is exporting as a executable jar from eclipse.

You should use maven to do the packaging, you have 2 possible solution:

1. [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html)
2. [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-assembly-plugin-3.0.0/index.html)